# Creating a counting table from data that is not cover all possible combinations and missing value is available in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I've successfully created a counting table from the data in df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','yes','yes','yes','no'],
'B':['yes','no','no','no','yes','yes','no','yes','yes','no'],
'C':['no','yes','yes','no','yes','no','no','no','yes','no']})
```

by using the following command:

```
df1.groupby(['A','B','C']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

I've got the counting table as follows:

```
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
index    A     B    C    count
0       no    no   no        1
1       no   yes   no        1
2       no   yes  yes        1
3      yes    no   no        2
4      yes    no  yes        2
5      yes   yes   no        2
6      yes   yes  yes        1
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

However, the possible values of A, B, C are {'yes','no'} which means all possible 
combinations should be equal to 2*2*2 = 8.  I could not get the exact all possible 
combinations because my data is not covered all cases.  The expected output should 
be the following:

```
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
index    A     B    C    count
0       no    no   no        1
1       no   yes   no        1
2       no    no  yes        0    <-- count = 0 because it does not exist in my data
3       no   yes  yes        1
4      yes    no   no        2
5      yes    no  yes        2
6      yes   yes   no        2
7      yes   yes  yes        1
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Furthermore, I could have missing values in my data.  For example, the data with 
missing values is the following code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','yes','yes','*','no'],
'B':['yes','*','no','no','yes','yes','no','yes','yes','no'],
'C':['no','yes','*','no','yes','no','no','no','yes','no']})
```

So, my data (with missing values) look like this

```
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
index    A     B    C
0      yes   yes   no
1      yes     *  yes
2      yes    no    *
3      yes    no   no
4       no   yes  yes
5       no   yes   no
6      yes    no   no
7      yes   yes   no
8        *   yes  yes
9       no    no   no
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

where * represents a missing value.  In this case, I still want to create my counting table
that contains all possible cases (similar to the 2nd table).  In this case, I need to ignore
any rows that has at least one missing values (index = 1, 2, and 8).  Therefore,
the expected  output should be like this.

```
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
index    A     B    C    count
0       no    no   no        1
1       no   yes   no        1
2       no    no  yes        0   <-- count = 0 because it does not exist in my data
3       no   yes  yes        1
4      yes    no   no        2
5      yes    no  yes        0   <-- count = 0 because of missing value in row 2
6      yes   yes   no        2
7      yes   yes  yes        0   <-- count = 0 because of missing value in row 1 and 8
--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

May I have your suggestions of how to overcome with the coverage problem and missing value problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a reindex after you get the size of your groupby

```
In [1]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['no', 'yes']] * 3, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [2]: print df1.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).size().reindex(idx).fillna(0).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})
     A    B    C  count
0   no   no   no      1
1   no   no  yes      0
2   no  yes   no      1
3   no  yes  yes      1
4  yes   no   no      2
5  yes   no  yes      2
6  yes  yes   no      2
7  yes  yes  yes      1

In [3]: print df2.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).size().reindex(idx).fillna(0).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})
     A    B    C  count
0   no   no   no      1
1   no   no  yes      0
2   no  yes   no      1
3   no  yes  yes      1
4  yes   no   no      2
5  yes   no  yes      0
6  yes  yes   no      2
7  yes  yes  yes      0
```

Comment: It works perfectly.  Thank you very much Colin.  Have a nice day \(^___^)/.

Comment: btw, it's interesting to think about what if the possible values of each variable is not the same.  e.g. A = ['yes','no'], B = ['low','medium','high'], C = ['north','east','west','south']?  I guess that I should modify idx as follows:

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['no', 'yes'],['low','medium','high'],['north','east','west','south'] , names=['A', 'B', 'C'])

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your coverage problem first.

The first step is to generate a dataframe with all the possibilities. To do so, I created a MultiIndex from a Cartesian product, and reset the index (like you did):

```
iterables = [['yes', 'no'], ['yes', 'no'], ['yes', 'no']]
df_all = pd.DataFrame(
        {'count': 0}, 
        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
    ).reset_index()
```

The second step uses `combine_first` to combine the result with your grouped dataframe (which I call `df` below). The problem is that `combine_first` works by index, so I had to reindex both dataframes first.

The easiest (if not most elegant) solution I found was to set as index the concatenation of columns `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
df = df1.groupby(['A','B','C']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
df.set_index(df['A'] + df['B'] + df['C'], inplace=True)
```

Now we're ready to use `combine_first`, dropping the temporary index at the end:

```
df_all.set_index(df_all['A'] + df_all['B'] + df_all['C'], inplace=True)
df.combine_first(df_all).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result:

```
     A    B    C  count
0   no   no   no      1
1   no   no  yes      0
2   no  yes   no      1
3   no  yes  yes      1
4  yes   no   no      2
5  yes   no  yes      2
6  yes  yes   no      2
7  yes  yes  yes      1
```

Comment: Ignoring missing values is much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much IanS.  The first problem has been solved.